# Adding Child Nodes to Parent Nodes treeview from database

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am working with a tree view system that loads info from a database that we have. I am trying to figure out how to add children nodes to a parent node based on the ID's in the database.

IE: ID of main profile = 1 check sub profiles and if the ID matches then add it as a child to the main. I have added the code that I am using below. I am able to load the Parent Nodes no problem, but I can't wrap my head around adding child nodes to the parent. Children should be added based on if the sID from the main matches the m_Sysid of the child then add the child.

```
        public void Main_Profile_Load()
    {
        string ConfigurationFile = @"C:\Profiles\cfg\verswitch.sdf";
        SqlCeConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            using (conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source =" + ConfigurationFile + "; Password =****"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select StoreID, StoreName, Children, ID from t_MainProfiles";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string sID = reader[0].ToString().Trim();
                    string sName = reader[1].ToString().Trim();
                    string sChild = reader[2].ToString().Trim();
                    string sSysID = reader[3].ToString().Trim();
                    TreeNode parent = new TreeNode();
                    parent.Text = sName+ " - "+sID;
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(parent);
                }
                reader.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Main Profiles Loaded. Retrieved ");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to locate Database");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

now her is the code for the sub profile load.

```
        public void Sub_Profile_Load()
    {
        string ConfigurationFile = @"C:\Profiles\cfg\verswitch.sdf";
        SqlCeConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            using (conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source =" + ConfigurationFile + "; Password =****"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select StoreID, Name, m_ProfileID from t_SubProfiles where Enabled = 1";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable sprofile = new DataTable();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DataRow row = sprofile.NewRow();
                    row["Storeid"] = (reader[0].ToString().Trim());
                    row["name"] = (reader[1].ToString().Trim());
                    row["mproID"] = (reader[2].ToString().Trim());
                    sprofile.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                reader.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Sub Profiles Loaded. Retrieved " + sprofile.Rows.Count);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to locate Database ");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

I just have no idea how to put them together.

Comment: How many children can a parent have?  1, 2, unlimited?  How many levels deep can this go?  Can a child have a child?

Comment: unlimited amount of children, but children can't have children